# Edit strings in every row of a column of a csv

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, date

I have a csv with a date column with dates listed as MM/DD/YY but I want to change the years from 00,02,03 to 1900, 1902, 1903 so that they are instead listed as MM/DD/YYYY

This is what works for me:

```
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].str.replace(r'00', '1900')
```

but I'd have to do this for every year up until 68 (aka repeat this 68 times). I'm not sure how to create a loop to do the code above for every year in that range. I tried this:

```
ogyear=00 
newyear=1900 
while ogyear <= 68:
    df2['date']=df2['Date'].str.replace(r'ogyear','newyear')
    ogyear += 1
    newyear += 1
```

but this returns an empty data set. Is there another way to do this?

I can't use datetime because it assumes that 02 refers to 2002 instead of 1902 and when I try to edit that as a date I get an error message from python saying that dates are immutable and that they must be changed in the original data set. For this reason I need to keep the dates as strings. I also attached the csv here in case thats helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
# create a data frame
d = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['20/01/00','20/01/20','20/01/50']})

# create year column
d['year'] = d['date'].str.split('/').str[2].astype(int) + 1900

# add new year into old date by replacing old year 
d['new_data'] = d['date'].str.replace('[0-9]*.$','') + d['year'].astype(str)

        date year   new_data
0   20/01/00 1900   20/01/1900
1   20/01/20 1920   20/01/1920
2   20/01/50 1950   20/01/1950
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the following way:

```
from datetime import datetime

# create a data frame with dates in format month/day/shortened year
d = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2/01/10','5/01/20','6/01/30']})

#loop through the dates in the dates column and add them 
#to list in desired form using datetime library,
#then substitute the dataframe dates column with the new ordered list

new_dates = []
for date in list(d['dates']):
    dat = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y'))
    dat = dat.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    new_dates.append(dat)
new_dates
d['dates'] = pd.Series(new_dates)
d
```